# Display series of images horizontally with overflow

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make my own image viewer, something that's better than what windows can provide.

I want to create an HTML page containing all my images but laid out horizontally as far as the monitor can go. And when I zoom in zoom out, the images also adjust sized and alignment.

I looked into IMGUR but I can't make sense of how they're achieving it. I'm guessing normal HTML can't do it, but some JS is involved as well? But I'm completely not sure.

I last did HTML 10 years ago. No spoonfeed needed, just a general direction.

my current code:

```
<html>
<body>
<video controls="" loop="" autoplay="" class="" src="somevideo"></video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'laid out horizontally as far as the monitor can go"? Do you mean the images extend beyond the edge of the screen and can be scrolled to, that they are sized initially so they all fit in one horizontal line or that they wrap when the reach the edge of the screen?

Comment: @Tom imagine I have an ultra wide, I want images to fill in the gaps. When I minimuze the browser into 2000 pixels wide for example, the rows adjust. It removes columns of images to fit the browser. Something like that

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Something like:

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap; width: 100vw; height: 100vh;">
  // your image elements
  <img style="flex: 1;" src="myImage.png">
</div>
```

Should give you what you're looking for (at least as far as I can tell).

Comment: I will give this a try